# WPF Frames - open links in external browser

Tags: html, wpf, browser

I have a Frame (used to display a local html file) in a WPF window. I would like that when the user clicks on a link or such, this is opened in an external browser window ( user's default web browser).

Any ideas how to go about this please?

Comment: Cannot test right now (away from Visual Studio), but this might be possible by attaching to the `Navigating` event of `YourFrame.NavigationService`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.navigating.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Just do it:

```
private void Frame_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    // You should make sure the links are different.
    if (IsExternalLink(e.Uri))
    {
        // open links in extbrowser.
        Process.Start(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
        // cancel the event, and Frame cannot perform navigation operation.
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Another solution:
ExternalLinks use the `Click` event instead of the `RequestNavigate` event.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextBlock>
   <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.google.com" TargetName="_top">
      Go Google!
   </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Sorry perhaps i didnt explai myself properly, i meant when the user clicks on a link within the Frame, im assuming theres some eventhandling to identify when the source url changes or such but i can seem to find the right trigger yet!

Answer (score 0):

This is a really informative article [Launching the Browser from a Hyperlink](http://laurenlavoie.com/avalon/159) and goes some to explaining what you need, read through the bullet points of "Browser (XBAP or Loose XAML)".

Setting the `TargetName="_self"` will open the link in the current frame, which I gather is what you want.